# How to count the number of hits against query ID through for Loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, count

I have the BLAST result data in table format. I am interested in the column one (query_ID) and column 3 (gene). Each query ID have multiple gene hits. I want to count the genes against each query ID.  For example "CSAI_contig04661_6" has 5 hits with gene. I want the output in the following format

```
CSAI_contig04661_6              GCST(3)
                                Y1099
                                SMC6A

 query_ID              subject_id  gene   organism  identity alignment_length mismatches gap_opens q.start q.end s.start s.end  evalue bit_score
1  CSAI_contig04661_6  sp|O65396  GCST    ARATH    86.03              408         56         1      72   478       1   408 0.0e+00     738.0
2  CSAI_contig04661_6  sp|Q681Y3 Y1099    ARATH    22.55              337        244        10     140   474     103   424 8.0e-09      56.6
3  CSAI_contig04661_6  sp|Q9FLR5 SMC6A    ARATH    24.27              103         66         3     156   249     342   441 4.6e+00      28.9
4  CSAI_contig04661_6  sp|Q9LQI7  GCST    ARATH    27.03               74         47         2     230   300      31   100 8.1e+00      27.7
5  CSAI_contig04661_6  sp|P56795  GCST    ARATH    28.95               76         49         4     436   509      15    87 8.4e+00      27.3
6  CSAI_isotig00001_4  sp|Q8VZE4 PP299    ARATH    29.63              108         55         5     213   307      10   109 1.6e+00      30.4
7  CSAI_isotig00001_4  sp|Q9M342 WAKLP    ARATH    28.28               99         64         3     261   355     320   415 1.9e+00      30.4
8  CSAI_isotig00001_4  sp|Q9ZUC1  QORL    ARATH    29.58               71         44         3     365   435     152   216 2.7e+00      29.6
9  CSAI_isotig00001_4  sp|Q5PNU3 AMSH3    ARATH    32.56               43         29         0     411   453     376   418 3.7e+00      29.3
10 CSAI_isotig00001_4  sp|F4K495 MOB2A    ARATH    26.09               46         28         1     417   456      39    84 5.5e+00      28.1
11 CSAI_isotig00001_4  sp|Q9CA60 C98A9    ARATH    36.59               41         24         1     271   309      91   131 9.6e+00      27.7
12 CSAI_isotig00004_3  sp|Q93V43  GCST    ARATH    27.84               97         55         2     135   220      92   184 2.0e-03      39.3
13 CSAI_isotig00004_3  sp|O64628 TXND9    ARATH    32.86               70         39         2     149   218      10    71 7.4e-01      30.4
14 CSAI_isotig00004_3  sp|O23212 U2A2A    ARATH    50.00               24         12         0     186   209      46    69 2.2e+00      29.6
15 CSAI_isotig00004_3  sp|Q9LE81   IRE    ARATH    26.67               75         41         2      15    75      44   118 5.6e+00      28.5
16 CSAI_isotig00004_3  sp|Q9LFN5 GLR25    ARATH    33.93               56         34         1     280   332     270   325 7.4e+00      28.1
```

I tried to count the how many time a gene is present against the query ID with the loop. But its not working. I am absolutely new in programming If I had made some mistake I hope you will forgive me. 
I need your suggestions to correct it.

```
testfile<-s_t38kbat
head(testfile)
col1<- trialfile$query_id
col2<- trialfile$gene
counting_columns(col1,col2)
length(col1)==length(col2)
length(col1) > 0
length(col2) > 0
col_element = col1[0]
start=0
end=0
large_dick = {}
for (i in (0:length(col1)))  element = col1[i] {
  if (element != col1_element) {
    start=end
    end=i
  }
  large_dick[col1_element] = count_unique_elements(col2, range(start:end)
  col1_element=element
  if (end < length(col1))
  large_dick[col1_element] = count_unique_elements(col2, range(end:length(col1))
}
return large_dick

count_unique_elements(col2, start, end)
disk{}
for (i in range(start,end)) element= col2[i] {
  if (disk has_key(element)) {
    val= disk.get(element)
    val=val+1
    disk[element] = val
  }
  else 
    disk[element] = 1
}
return(disk)  

print(counting_columns(cat1,cat2))
}
```

Comment: `library(dplyr)

group_by(s_t38kbat,query_ID,gene) %>%
  summarize(n=n())`

Comment: Yes I did and get output. But I would like to do it with loop.